# InstallShield 2010 Basic MSI Major Upgrade Error 2753

Tags: installshield-2010, major-upgrade, basic-msi

I am using InstallShield 2010 Basic MSI Project for installing a product. Now I've created a Major Upgrade item for performing a major upgrade from previous version.

In the project I have a EXE file which registers a 3rd party component, which needs to called with different cmd line arguments during Installation, Uninstallation.

I have created two custom actions for this (CA: EXE, Installed with the Product), which was working fine in the previous builds.

1) **REGMYCOMP** - For Installation - **Deferred Execution** - Sequenced before **InstallFinalize** (Condition: **Not Installed**)

2) **UNREGMYCOMP** - For Uninstallation - **Deferred Execution** - Sequenced before **RemoveFiles** (Condition: **(REMOVE = "ALL") OR (IS_MAJOR_UPGRADE)**)

**UNREGMYCOMP** CA fails during the major upgrade (executing the MSI directly using MSIEXEC.EXE) with the following error

> ERROR 2753 The File 'xxxx.exe' is not marked for installation.

The same thing happens when I try to uninstall the product from the Control Panel ARP entry.